# How to effectively communicate a promotion to colleagues

Tags: communication, team, promotion, team-role

I was recently informed that I am being promoted. I'd like to know how to effectively go about communicating this to my colleagues before the promotion is made public knowledge so as to ensure that it won't place any strain on my team's dynamic.

Comment: Congratulations! Will you be leaving the team as a result of your promotion?

Comment: Thanks! I will be staying on the same team and working with the same people.

Comment: Why is it so important for you to announce it before the official announcement? If they change their mind later, you will end up with an egg on your face.

Comment: Often, your manager will announce this. If s/he doesn't, the canonical solution is "woo-hoo! I've been promoted! I'm buying a round of ${beverages} and appetisers after work; meet me at ${localRestaurant} at ${time}."

Comment: @MaskedMan - Good point. I just want to make sure that everyone is ok with it when it does get announced, but maybe I'm overthinking it.

Comment: @keshlam - Excellent suggestion!

Comment: If that's your only reason, I would say don't bother with it. There will always be people who are not "okay" when a coworker gets promoted. It is their problem, not yours. You announcing it before the boss does isn't going to make them feel okay, it is more likely to be the opposite! Moreover, if someone is "not okay", you still can't do anything about it.

Comment: You're probably overthinking it. Or are you perhaps not OK with it and projecting your not-OK-ness?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ideally, you don't communicate it but your immediate supervisor does. They can call together a meeting of your team to say something like "THE DOCTOR is going to be doing X. This change has not yet been formally announced, but I wanted to let you know what is happening before you see the announcement. Y will be taking over THE DOCTOR's work on project A. Z will be handling (some other aspect of your current job)..."

I felt it was particularly important to do it that way when I was leaving a team leader role and would have no authority over that team in my new job. I couldn't say how people in the old team should be assigned after I left it. Of course, I had been closely involved planning and advising my manager on how to keep my old team working well.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll be staying on the same team in this new role. Also, I've known one person on the team for a long time. We were friends before he joined and I got him the job with this company, so I kind of feel like I should say something to him directly beforehand.

Comment: Upon further thought I think your suggestion is probably the best way to proceed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since you're staying on the same team, doing similar work, but with added leadership duties, you should allow your management to inform your team, instead of doing it yourself. Doing so yourself would more than likely be seen as presumptuous and overly eager on your part. Imagine how it might be interpreted, *"I'm being promoted, and I'm going to be telling you what to do from now on."*

You should encourage your manager to inform the team before an official announcement is made.

After you begin your new duties, it will require extra effort on your part to help your team know you're still on their side, while at the same time, having to balance their desires with business priorities. Congratulations, and Good Luck!